# Set of all matrices with determinant 0, non-zero

Tags: matrices, elementary-set-theory, determinant, inverse

I was assigned this problem in class: Let $f: M(n, \mathbb R) \rightarrow \mathbb R $ be given by $f(X) = det(X)$. Identify the sets $f^{-1}(0)$ and $f^{-1}(\mathbb R^*)$, where $\mathbb R^*$ denotes the set of nonzero real numbers.

For $f^{-1}(0)$, I understand that I'm looking for the set of all $n \times n$ matrices with determinant 0, but how do I express this in set theoretic notation that works for matrices of any order? I mean, for a matrix of order 2, $f^{-1}(0) = \{(a_{ij})| a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21} =0, a_{ij} \in \mathbb R \}$. But this can't be extended to higher orders. I'm having the same issue with $f^{-1}(\mathbb R^*)$, where I'm looking for the set of all matrices with nonzero determinant. But how do I express this in set theoretic notation?

Is there any neat way that captures all such matrices, for both $f^{-1}(\mathbb R^*)$ and $f^{-1}(0)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We usually denote the set of $n\times n$ real matrices with non-zero determinant by $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ - this is called the general linear group, hence the $GL$. Doing this we'd have $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^*) = GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ and $f^{-1}(0) = M(n, \mathbb{R})\setminus GL(n, \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Oh, but we haven't been taught about groups yet. We haven't even defined the inverse of a matrix. This question is primarily from set theory in a section titled Inverse images. So I was wondering if there's an elementary answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

You would have $f^{-1}(0)=\{A\in M(n,\Bbb R):\det(A)=0\}$ And $f^{-1}(\Bbb R^*)=\{A\in M(n,\Bbb R):\det(A)\ne 0\}$

Or you could have:

$f^{-1}(0)=\{A\in M(n,\Bbb R):A \text{ has at least one eigenvalue $\lambda=0$}\}$

$f^{-1}(0)=\{A\in M(n,\Bbb R):A \text{ has all eigenvalue $\lambda\ne 0$}\}$

Comment: Haha, I see that this works very well indeed! :) But is there a more explicit (constructive) way of expressing such $A$, which doesn't use the definition of the inverse of a matrix?

Comment: @JobinIdiculla you can't really write a closed form without some indirect reference to the notion of an inverse, but i will put another slightly more constructive argument

Answer (score 1):

Since $\det A=0$ if and only if $A$ is invertible, we could write $f^{-1}(\Bbb R^*)$ and $f^{-1}(0)$ as
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(\Bbb R^*) &= \{A\in M_n(\Bbb R):\exists B\in M_n(\Bbb R),AB= I\} \\
f^{-1}(0) &=\{A\in M_n(\Bbb R):\not\exists B\in M_n(\Bbb R),AB=I\}
\end{align*}

Comment: Is there a more elementary way of expressing it? Because the inverse of a matrix hasn't been defined yet in our class.

Answer (score 1):

- $f^{-1}(0)$ is the set of singular (non invertible) matrices of $M_n(\Bbb R)$ i.e. the set of matrices with rank strictly less than $n$ and
- $f^{-1}(\Bbb R^*)$ is the set of invertible matrices of $M_n(\Bbb R)$ i.e. the set of matrices with full rank denoted by $GL_n(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Is there a more elementary way of expressing it? Because the inverse and rank of a matrix hasn't been defined yet, in my class.

Comment: As I said I think that the best expression is to say invertible or not invertible.